# Induction introduces 'bad name'

Tags: isabelle, isar

In the below code:

```
inductive T :: "alpha list ⇒ bool" where
 Tε : "T []" |
 TaTb : "T l ⟹ T r ⟹ T (l @ a#(r @ [b]))"

lemma Tapp: "⟦T l;  T r⟧ ⟹ T (l@r)"
proof (induction l arbitrary: r rule: T.induct)
  case Tε
  then show ?case by (simp add: Tε)
next
  case (TaTb l r) then show ?case
```

I am in the state:

```
proof (prove)
using this:
    T l
    T ra__
    T ?r ⟹ T (l @ ?r)
    T ?r ⟹ T (ra__ @ ?r)
    T r

goal (1 subgoal):
 1. T ((l @ a # ra__ @ [b]) @ r)
```

However, I cannot reference this `ra__`, getting `Bad name: "ra__"⌂`, however, I need to reference it. How do I bind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof text is trying to give two different variables the name `r`. For your case pattern try a different name, e.g. `case(TaTb l r')`. You will get the same proof state except `r'` instead of `ra__`.

Comment: thanks for spotting! I do have to say that `l` and `r` were suggested by Isabelle's automatic case-splitting completion, and that Isabelle's behavior does not really make the underlying issue discoverable